# How to turn on/off the monitor(s)?

Tags: delphi, winapi, screen, power-management

I wanted to be able to **turn on/off my monitors** from a **Delphi** script, from **Windows XP to 7**.

I have searched within the **Delphi** section on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and didn't find the answer.

I also found many samples which doesn't work anymore on Windows 7 (only with XP).

Comment: The first results googling for "to turn on/off my monitors from a Delphi script" pretty much all list "your" solution.

Comment: I agree Mat ; I just add it because I didn't find it on stackoverflow (and as I have read [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))...

Comment: My [`TSystemState`](http://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/classes/systemstate/readme.html) does this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have successfully tested this on Windows XP **and** Windows 7:

```
const
  MONITOR_ON      = -1;
  MONITOR_OFF     =  2;
  MONITOR_STANDBY =  1;
```

To turn off the monitor:

```
  SendMessage(Application.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_OFF);
```

To turn on the monitor:

```
  SendMessage(Application.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_ON);
```

Comment: If you know why it hangs with the broadcast... I tried with   Application.ProcessMessages; without better result!

Comment: You probably need to use PostMessage instead of SendMessage.

Comment: I just test it! and it works! Thanks a lot! I update the second part of my answer.

Comment: Do not broadcast the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message to all windows. Just send it to one of your own windows, which then should run the message through default processing. If you send it to all windows, then you might end up sending the message to a window that processes `WM_SYSCOMMAND`s in a special way, making the resulting behavior unpredictable.

Comment: ok, I see ; for instance, if one app checks this specific command to switch on the display, or switch off the computer instead, it won't work as expected!

Comment: @Whiler: Exactly. You only have to send the message to one (of your own) window. As long as the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` parameters are right, the message processing machinery will take care of turning off the monitors for you without requiring you to broadcast the message.

Comment: Ok, so, I remove the broadcast part from my answer ;o)

Comment: @In silico, better directly pass to `DefWindowProc`. As side remark - such broadcasts (yes, `HWND_BROADCAST` applies) should be sent using `SendMessageTimeout`. Thats why `SendMessage` never returns in some cases.